# Is there alternative to arduino IDE program ESP8266 and ESP32 with arduino toolchain?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, ide, esp32

I use ESP8266 and ESP32 with arduino toolchain rather than pure arduino hardware.
Arduino IDE is standard and proven but what are the other IDE and advantage/disadvantage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an exhaustive list. Most **advantages** will be subjective.

- [UECIDE](https://github.com/UECIDE/UECIDE) - Wide variety of boards, not only Arduino, better editor and serial monitor, plug-in based modules.
- [PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/platformio-ide) (Available as plugin for [Atom editor](https://github.com/atom/atom), [MS Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/) and [Eclipse IDE](http://docs.platformio.org/en/stable/ide/eclipse.html)) - Automatic library updating, one `ini` file that defines project settings and external libraries, making projects portable to other users without having to download all external libraries.
- [Arduino IDE for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualMicro.ArduinoIDEforVisualStudio) - For those who like VS?
- [Arduino Makefiles](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) - More like old-school command-line coding, Linux-style development. Not an IDE.
- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/april/article4.php) - Another quite popular IDE outside Arduino world.
- [Atmel/Microchip Studio 7](https://www.microchip.com/avr-support/atmel-studio-7) - Provided by the manufacturer of the AVR chips. "Arduino" sketches may not compile without changes to make them more like standard C++.

Comment: **VisualMicro** is a powerfull addon to Visual Studio 201x (no command line needed and intellisense work). That's the best solution for ESP/arduino developpement in my opinion. The free version is really complete to make tests.

**VisualGDB** is also a good tool to debug (JTAG necessary) but only for ESP tool chain (arduino could be added is future release said in the forum...).

Answer (score 2):

For example, Eclipse IDE with Sloeber plugin is much better than Arduino IDE. You have all the features of Eclipse (coloring, error highlighting, auto-complete, open declaration ('drill down' to libraries), ...*). And every project has own settings (board settings, port, programmer ...). And the Arduino IDE buttons Upload, Verify, Session Monitor are there and the Arduino toolchain too.

*... projects management, version control, TODO lists, outline, ...

Comment: I have a very bad experience of ECLIPSE at school last year. Lot of parameters hard to adjust and too much bugs... Visual studio (and code version) are robust days after days.